# JAVASCRIPT : create dynamic key in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
var jsonUiid = "sdfsdf";
a={
        [jsonUiid] : {
        "heading":"title"
        }
};
```

Tried directly in developer tools.
The above code works in all browsers. 
It fails in Internet Explorer. Please help.

If we don't square bracket[], it directly gets "jsonUiid" rather than the actual value defined above.

Comment: `a = {}; a[jsonUiid] = { "heading" : "title"};`

Comment: FYI, this has nothing whatsoever to do with JSON. JSON is a *textual* data-exchange format.

Answer (score 1):

Computed property names are part of ES6 which is currently not fully supported by all browsers. You can set object property with old-style [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation):

```
var jsonUiid = "sdfsdf";
var a = {};
a[jsonUiid] = {
    "heading": "title"
};
```